# Is it possible to minimize the unlock section of the lock screen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens

Sometimes your widgets take up a lot of space. The unlock section also  takes up a lot of space if you use a PIN or password. Is there any way to minimize it?

Comment: Related: [Maximize Lockscreen widget?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36399)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to minimize the unlock section by default in the lock screen section of the Settings app.

**Maximize Widgets**
Show widgets maximized and the unlock minimized when the screen is turned on.